# How to sign data in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, rsa, .net-core-3.0

#### Question

Is there a way to cryptographically sign data (RSA or anything that is considered to be cryptographically secure) and verify that signature so that the signing is done in one HTTP request to an endpoint and verification is done in another HTTP request with another endpoint?

#### Background

I'm trying to implement signed URLs. The idea is to protect files or other resources that are usually served via GET (images, PDFs, etc...) by providing signed URL (URLs with a cryptographically signed payload at the end of the URL) which is then validated when requested.

So you might have something like an API returning:

```
{
    "image": "http://api.example.com?key=..."
}
```

where `...` is the signed payload (which usually contains the user ID, the expiration time and some kind of identifier for the resource).

Then when the browser calls for `http://api.example.com?key=...`, what's in the `...` is verified which then either grants access to the image or not.

#### What have I tried

I read about `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, which seems to automatically generate the private key with which stuff is encrypted, but I've also read that it's not thread safe, therefore registering `RSACryptoServiceProvider` as a singleton is not an option.

I'm guessing registering it as scoped or transient would not work when you want the same private key for two different requests (URL generation and file streaming).

Comment: You're flicking between "sign" and "decrypt" -- signing is not encryption. You probably want to be signing rather than encrypting/decrypting, but get the distinction clear in your head

Comment: @canton7 I'm thinking something like JWT tokens more or less. Where you share a string that contains both payload (base64 encoded I think?) and a signature.

Comment: Right, that's not encryption. You probably want to be using a [HMAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmac?view=netframework-4.8). Create a new instance each time you want to sign something.

Comment: JWT's are normally signed with private part of an asymetric key and the public part is published for the JWT consumers to validate the issuer.

Comment: Generally you would create the RSA key *pair* in advance, and make sure that the public key is registered. You never create a singleton of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` because that's the *algorithm*. Instead, you store the keys, and then create an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` instance for each thread (or even for each use, because the *algorithms state* and creation time of such instances is minimal. They are not thread safe because *they don't need to be*.

Comment: With registered, I mean that it [the public key] is known and trusted in advance by the receiving party. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm not sure I need a public key either TBH (I don't think I care that the client is able to verify the token/key). The idea is just to give the user (untrusted) a link of some sort that authorises him/her to view a resource. The simplest idea would be to just append the access/session token to the URL but that is dangerous if the user copy and pastes the link around. Maybe a short lived JWT is the solution here?

Comment: If you're verifying the URL yourself then *you* are the receiver. The user is just the one that stores the signature for some time. Of course, in that case, you might also use e.g. HMAC which uses a single symmetric key instead of a signature. The only advantage of an asymmetric scheme is that you don't need the private key for verification.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Great thanks. If you put that into an answer I can accept it. Otherwise I might as well just remove the question.